# WebView2 Interaction ViewModel (WPF/C#) --> RestrictDomain

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, viewmodel, webview2

Dear Colleges on the web,

I want to use WebView2 in my app however I want RestrictDomain in my viewmodel file which normally gets defined in the view.xaml.cs file. Is this possible to bind it in some way shape or form? nor the code looks like:

Xaml:

```
<DockPanel>
    <wv2:WebView2
        x:Name="webView2Name"
        Source="{Binding weblink}"
        NavigationStarting="{Binding RestrictDomain}"
    />
</DockPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public string weblink { get; set; }

    public void RestrictDomain(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        string uri = args.Uri;
        if (!uri.StartsWith("https://www.google.com"))
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
            webView2Name.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"alert('{uri} is outside of domain')");
        }
    }
```

webView2Name in the viewmodel is not regonized ofcourse so this is just an other problem above the other problem.(the weblink is set somewhere else)

if anyone can find or knows any solution to it it would be very welcome.

greatings,
Its me Jessi

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can bind the WebView2.Source to your ViewModel, and it should be possible to bind your navigation event as well to your ViewModel.
The Source should be bind to an Uri type (not a string)

If you want to bind a property/event from your view to your view model, then the datacontext must be defined in your view/xaml ; something like this (assuming your namespace is 'YourNameSpace' and your viewmodel class is 'ViewModel') :

```
<Window x:Class="YourNameSpace.View "
    ....
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    ...
    d:DataContext="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
<Window.Resources>
```

Also, your weblink set should raise an event in order to notify any change to the view.
Usually your ViewModel (or your base class) would implement the INotifyPropertyChanged for this.

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Uri_webUri;
   public Uri WebUri
   {
       get => _webUri; 
       set
       {
          _name = value;
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(WebUri)));
       }
   }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Your binding in XAML should now be:

```
Source="{Binding WebUri}"
```

Last thing is wiring the NavigationStarting event to the view model. I have done it in the past, but struggled with it and in the end I used the interaction triggers for this. It worked but maybe there are better solutions for this. The interaction trigger I used for the webview event was 'NavigationCompleted' ; so maybe you can use it as well and replace NavigationCompleted with NavigationStarting.

```
    <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding WebUri}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="NavigationCompleted">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=WebViewNavigationCompleted}" 
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
                           
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </wv2:WebView2>
```

Note: I used MVVMLight (nuget package: MvvmLightLibs) in my application and in your View/Xaml you should add":

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
```

I hope this helps you a bit further. Good luck with it.